# How to send mail to multiple recipients in php through mailchimp

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am searching for a php code to send bulk mail through mailchimp. I have signup mailchimp account. I got a code from mailchimp. I use my api key to run the code.But not working. The code is given below

```
<?php
 $apikey = '*********';

 $to_emails = array('you@example.com', 'your_mom@example.com');
 $to_names = array('You', 'Your Mom');

$message = array(
'html'=>'Yo, this is the <b>html</b> portion',
'text'=>'Yo, this is the *text* portion',
'subject'=>'This is the subject',
'from_name'=>'Me!',
'from_email'=>'verifed@example.com',
'to_email'=>$to_emails,
'to_name'=>$to_names
);

$tags = array('WelcomeEmail');

$params = array(
'apikey'=>$apikey,
'message'=>$message,
'track_opens'=>true,
'track_clicks'=>false,
'tags'=>$tags
 );

 $url = "http://us13.sts.mailchimp.com/1.0/SendEmail";

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?'.http_build_query($params));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 echo $result;
 curl_close ($ch);

 $data = json_decode($result);
 echo "Status = ".$data->status."\n";
 ?>
```

I am new to this code. It shows

```
status=
```

Is there anything more to add to this?
Anybody please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Does `$result` show anything?

Comment: No. it shows nothing.

Comment: it could be the url issue then, check with mailchimp

Comment: how to check that?  this is my full code. no other code or script is associate with this. even then is it due to url issue?

Comment: `$url = "http://us13.sts.mailchimp.com/1.0/SendEmail";` this url seems to have problem. You can try copy this url and manually open using your browser, it should show 404 error

Comment: Which should be the url? how we get the url?

Answer (score 0):

STS is MailChimp's long-disabled transactional pre-cursor to Mandrill. You'll want to either use Mandrill if you already have a paid MailChimp account or another service like Mailgun.

Comment: I have a free mailchimp account. can I get any other code instead?

Comment: You will not be able to send this sort of email with a free mailchimp account.

Comment: any other method to send bulk mail?

Comment: If you want to send bulk email, just use MailChimp the normal way (by adding people to a list and then sending a campaign to them). Or, as stated above, use a different service like Mailgun.